# DotNet Core IConfiguration.GetSection is new

Tags: .net, .net-core

My application was working, I was able to get values from appsettings.json, when I had to change file structure of my project, I am no longer able to get config details.

My config file (appsettings.json) looks like this:

{ "Jwt": { "Key":"bs::", "Issuer":"SomeIssuer" } }

Note: This is only the "Jwt" part.

When I call:

```
var jwtConfig = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt");
jwtConfig["Key"];
```

`jwtConfig` value is null. I also tried:

```
Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Key").Value
```

But no luck.

When I run "dotnet run watch" everything works just fine. But If I try and debug using vs code, I get an error saying that the string is null.

My Program.cs file:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
                Seed.SeedUsers(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured during migration.");
            }
        }
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(WebBuilder => {
            WebBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Relevant lines in Startup.cs file:

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x =>
        {
            x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors();


        var jwtConfig = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt");
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtConfig["Key"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about other settings? Are they null as well or only just this?

Comment: @PeterCsala, I edited the post with the Jwt part of my appsettings.json.

Comment: Did you check that the corresponding json file is listed under the `Configuration.Providers`? You should looking for a `JsonConfigurationProvider`, where the `Source` should be a `PhysicalFileProvider` and it's `Path` should point to the right asppsettings.json file. (At debug time in VS it is quite easy to check)

Comment: @PeterCsal, Thanks a lot, you helped me solve my problem. After checking my JsonConfigurationProvider's path, I noticed that it was pointing to the wrong path, I then updated my launch.json fil, changing the "cwd" value to go two folders up. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. I left an answer where I capture the process in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out the one of the `Configuration`'s `Providers` was misconfigured.

You can check this easily at debug time by going through the following process:

1. Place a break point inside a `ConfigureServices` at that line where you refer to the `Configuration` object.
2. Start your application.
3. Hover over the Configuration object and open the `Providers` collection
4. Look for those providers which are `JsonConfigurationProvider`
5. Check the `Source` of these and look for `PhysicalFileProvider`
6. Check their `Path` to point to the right file

[image: Check the registered Configuration Providers]